# Error When using a Macro in C++ to validate an IP

Tags: c++, macros

I need to check if my ipaddr is equal to 0.0.0.0 using a macro. I wrote the code as below, but keeps on getting an error.

```
#define IPV4_ZEROVAL_CHECK(ip) {int d1,d2,d3,d4; return (4 == sscanf(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &d1, &d2, &d3, &d4)) ? ((d1 == 0 && d2 == 0 && d3 == 0 && d4 ==0) ? 0 : 1) : 0;};

int main()
{
    char ip[16] = "0.0.1.0";
    int x = 99;
    x=  IPV4_ZEROVAL_CHECK (ipaddr);
    printf("Value of x=%d \n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

while compiling I am getting error as follows

```
ipbox [root] # gcc test.cpp -lstdc++ -o test.o
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
test.cpp:9: error: expected `;' before '{' token
```

I am missing something but just cant het my head around it. If i write is as function, it works well. I am curious why it doesn't work as a MACRO

Comment: Why using MACRO instead of regular (inline) function ?

Comment: Pls don't use a macro for that

Comment: additionally to what have been said, the ipaddr variable is missing

Comment: That macro should be a function. Too sort out why it's not doing what you want, begin by copying and pasting the code in the macro into your `main` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to implement this as a macro then you need to remove the `return` from inside the macro. You can't assign the "result" of your macro to a variable as it is not a single statement.

```
#include <cstdio>

#define IPV4_ZEROVAL_CHECK(ip, result) {int d1,d2,d3,d4; result = (4 == sscanf(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &d1, &d2, &d3, &d4)) ? ((d1 == 0 && d2 == 0 && d3 == 0 && d4 ==0) ? 0 : 1) : 0;};

int main()
{
    char ip[16] = "0.0.1.0";
    int x = 99;
    IPV4_ZEROVAL_CHECK (ip, x);
    printf("Value of x=%d \n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

There's no advantage to implementing this as a macro. Leave it as a function, if its small enough the compiler will inline it when compiled in release mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you expand the macro, you will see what the problem is:

```
int main()
{
    char ip[16] = "0.0.1.0";
    int x = 99;
    x= {int d1,d2,d3,d4; return (4 == sscanf(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &d1, &d2, &d3, &d4)) ? ((d1 == 0 && d2 == 0 && d3 == 0 && d4 ==0) ? 0 : 1) : 0;};
    printf("Value of x=%d \n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

The `{int d1,...}` is not an expression, and the compiler is expecting an expression and a semicolon between the `x=` and the `{`.

If you desperately want a macro for some reason, you can write a much simpler one:

```
#define IPV4_ZEROVAL_CHECK(ip) (strcmp(ip, "0.0.0.0") == 0)
```

But I would recommend the function

```
bool IPV4_ZEROVAL_CHECK(const std::string& ip)
{
    return ip == "0.0.0.0";
}
```

or - the simplest solution - define a constant that you compare to:

```
const std::string zero_IP = "0.0.0.0";

int main()
{
    char ip[16] = "0.0.1.0";
    bool isZero = ip == zero_IP;
    std::cout << "The value is " << isZero;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Macros work by textual substitution prior to the actual compilation process.

**Example:**

Given this definition:

```
#define FOO(bar) {return bar * 2;};
```

the textual substitution for this line:

```
x =  FOO (ipaddr);
```

results in following C code seen by the compiler:

```
x =  {return ipaddr * 2;};
```

which is incorrect C code.

- your C text book should cover this
- in your case (as in most cases)  is is better to use a function instead of a macro.